# Default colors does not work for `tailwind.macro`

Tags: create-react-app, postcss, emotion, tailwind-css

I have a React app, attempting for `tailwind.macro` to work within
`emotion` notations.
I am using `customize-cra` to rewire the app, and `${tw`WHATEVER`}` is successfully working.
However, it does not seem to inherit the original color themes from
`tailwind` and I am looking for a solution.
Here is the project:
https://github.com/minagawah/cra-ts-emotion-tailwind-solution

As described in the README, I tried
(1) [using babel macro](https://github.com/minagawah/cra-ts-emotion-tailwind-solution#what-babel),
and (2) [using PostCSS plugins](https://github.com/minagawah/cra-ts-emotion-tailwind-solution#what-postcss).
I thought it's the `backgroundSize` problem
as it is discussed in
[this issue](https://github.com/bradlc/babel-plugin-tailwind-components/issues/13#issuecomment-430163181), but no luck.

Here is how I use the `tw` macro notation in the app:

#### # `./src/App.tsx`

```js
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import tw from 'tailwind.macro';

const Button = styled.button`
  ${tw`mt-4 p-2 text-white bg-red-600`}
`;
```

And it currently works
[because I applied a workaround](https://github.com/minagawah/cra-ts-emotion-tailwind-solution/blob/292036acaf6824b3ce4845d70eef0b54d3ed6720/src/tailwind.config.js#L121)
for this.

It should apply the default tailwind color themes without the workaround I've applied.
I have been trying to figure out ways, but so far, no luck...

Please, I desperately need a help on this...

**EDIT: (2019-09-22)

While I was struggling for `bg-red` to work, I just found out there's no such thing as `bg-red` by default... That was something I needed to manually add in `tailwind.config.js`.**

**Problem solved.**

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        red: '#e53e3e',
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        red: '#e53e3e',
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issues i fixed by copying  the default value from  the tailwindcss github  in tailwind.config.js.
here is the link to tailwindcss default value
https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/blob/master/stubs/defaultConfig.stub.js#L5